# Sphinx search with filtering by coordinates

Tags: sphinx

I have this query:

```
select id, post_category_name , title, description,WEIGHT(), 
  geodist(50.95, 24.69, latitude, longitude) dist 
from serv1 where match('@(title,description) searchText ) and dist < 2000000000000;
```

in my DB post have `latitude: 50.85`, and `longitude: 24.69`
In result I have distance:`893641` but real distance is `11119.49` meters.
I also tried convert input coordinates to radians but still have not correct distance.
What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: " I also tried convert input coordinates to radians " ... did you change the coordinates in the geodist function call, AND the values in the latitude/longitude **attributes** ?

Comment: I used  "double lat1rad = Math.toRadians(latitude) " in my java code when build search query. How do I need to change latitude/longitude in attributes? Now I have  sql_attr_float = Latitude ,
    sql_attr_float = Longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
geodist(50.95, 24.69, latitude, longitude, {in=deg}) dist
```

(note {in=deg})

It returns the number close to the one you're expecting:

```
mysql> select geodist(50.95, 24.69, 50.85, 24.69, {in=deg});
+-----------------------------------------------+
| geodist(50.95, 24.69, 50.85, 24.69, {in=deg}) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 11124.928711                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are the best))

Answer (score 0):

Based on code in one of your other questions, would do something like

```
sql_query = select  p.id,  ... , \
         RADIANS(l.Latitude) as latitude, RADIANS(l.Longitude) as longitude FROM ...
```

using the MySQL function to convert the stored degreee value to radions for the attribute.

The...

```
sql_attr_float = latitude
sql_attr_float = longitude
```

would be unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for help, but i have this error "(ERROR: index 'serv1': sql_query: FUNCTION serv.deg2rad does not exist (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:3306/serv). " Do you have any other solution for me?

Comment: also tried radians(latitude) and  radians(logitude),  but got not valid distance : 4053030

Comment: ok, sorry, yes the mysql function is RADIANS(). deg2rad is the PHP function name! ... did you also change valuesin the query to radians?

Comment: only "{in=deg}" helped me